# Need direction for getting started with a business profile site

Tags: c#, java, php, html, flash

I am building a new website, which you can see at http://www.kristalcapljina.99k.org.

While I have some web design experience, I need help in knowing what I should research to add some specific functionality to the site.

The first bit I want to add is an area where business owners can list their business' information, such as the address or contact information.  They should also be able to login later to change the information.  I assume this will need some sort of database, but don't know where to begin looking.

Second, I wish to add a map that highlights the locations of these businesses.

Any help direction you can give me to get started would be most appreciated.

Comment: This is a poorly asked question, but it is a legitimate one. Let's get it cleaned up, not closed. It isn't spam.

Answer (score 1):

You want to embed a Google Map onto your site, using the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html).